# Returning an object - javaScript

Tags: javascript, object, return, return-value

The function below "foo" doesn't work. I would like a way to get the output shown below, working around the principle shown in "foo".

```
function foo() {
    var i;

    i = "hello world";
    i.a = "hello kitten";
    i.b = "hello... Is there anybody out there?"

    return i; // This doesn't work
}
```

This is what I want:

```
    alert(foo()); // "hello world"
    var bar = foo();
    alert(bar.a); // "hello kitten"
    alert(bar.b); // "hello... Is there anybody out there?"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a string object instead of a string value.

```
i = new String("hello world");
```

Comment: In that case, `alert(foo());` might show something like `{ [String: 'hello world'] a: 'hello kitten', b: 'hello... Is there anybody out there?' }`?

Comment: Thank you sir! Brilliant (and so quick!). Works perfectly, implementing now. (Will wait a few hours to be polite before I accept).